# How to fit a view in centre of the main screen programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to set a view "CenterView" in the centre of the main screen...im using the below code to set it in centre. But it is differs for various screen...I need to know how to set a frame for a view in a centre position of a main screen that should fit for all the screens.Could somebody please help me!.

```
UIView *centerview=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-280)/2,(topview.frame.origin.y+topview.frame.size.height)+60,280,185)];
    centerview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [mainview addSubview:centerview];
```

Comment: That's not how we present code here.

Comment: Why don't you use the same math for your y that you use for your x?  Better yet, use autolayout with constraints.

Comment: @Paulw11 sir I have to do by this way sir, I'm asked to do this in programmatically without autolayout.

Comment: I don't know how to set a frame for a view in the centre of the screen as im new for objective c

Comment: @Preethi - first, auto layout can be used programmatically. Second, if you absolutely do not want to use auto layout... Are you having problems with **horizontal** center, **vertical center** or both? And, what is `mainview`? You're adding `centerview` as a subview to `mainview` ... is it possible `mainview` is not centered?